# Google Adsense for content shows textbox instead of ads

Tags: google-adsense

I have Google Adsense for Content set up for my blog. It shows advertisements below the post content on each single post.

However, instead of this showing up:

> Ads by Google ad1 ad2 ad3 ...

This shows up:

> Ads by Google View ads about: [textbox] [button]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google Adsense help forum, it wasn't anything related to the code.

It was because I hadn't verified everything Adsense related yet (like my PIN), so that PSAs were shown. Therefore, no ads were shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had used plugin my wordpress blog but that did not worked well. Then I updated the php file and added the code there. Was not that difficult.
http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/
Will find name of file and post here.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the format options for AdSense Link-unit ads.    (Not one that many people use, so you may not have seen it before).

Your blog uses Wordpress?   So am I right that you cannot include Javascript yourself .. that means you must be using a plug-in to put the ad in?   So you'll need to change the plugin.

(I've never used Wordpress, so there are some big assumptions there ... could be on the wrong track totally.   But I'm sure it's not an AdSense problem.)

Comment: You're certainly right that the blog uses a Wordpress plugin to inject the Google code in there. However, all it does is simply put the Javascript code. If you view source, it'll look the same.